# how to prove whether statement is true or false?

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)= x^n+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k x^k$ and $q(x)= x^n+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k x^k$

be two polynomials with real coefficients such that $x=3$ is a common root of the equations $p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=0$.

Then the expression is true or false?

$3a_1+a_0=3b_1+b_0$

Comment: Its true for second degree polynomials. Otherwise, it's false. Take for example $(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)=(x-3)(x-2)x$

Comment: That title is extremely vague.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a counterexample. Let $n=3$, so
$$p(x)=x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0\ \mbox {and }\ q(x)=x^3+b_2x^2+b_1x+b_0$$
$p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=0$ implies:
$$27+9a_2+3a_1+a_0=0\ \mbox {and }\ 27+9b_2+3b_1+b_0=0$$
Let
$$a_0=-30,\ a_1=1,\ a_2=0$$
and
$$b_0=-27,\ b_1=1,\ b_2=-\frac{1}{3}.$$
Then 
$$27+9a_2+3a_1+a_0=0\ \mbox {and }\ 27+9b_2+3b_1+b_0=0$$
but 
$$3a_1+a_0=-27\not=-24=3b_1+b_0$$